# Hide overflow behind stacked div with transparent background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a layout that contains a `fixed` div (`#navigation`) that has buttons. The layout also includes scrollable content (`.card`).

`#navigation` currently has a green background for demo purposes. Like so:

```css
#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  background: green;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation"><button id="btn1">Button</button>
  <button id="btn2">Button</button>
  <button id="btn3">Button</button>
  <button id="btn4">Button</button>
</div>
```

I would like to hide the any part of any `.card` element as soon as it goes behind the green background. So, I use z-index stacking order and it works well. Like so:

```css
#card-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #131418;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: inline-block
}

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  z-index: 1;
  background: green;
  padding: 25px;
}

#main {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <div id="navigation"><button id="btn1">Button</button>
    <button id="btn2">Button</button>
    <button id="btn3">Button</button>
    <button id="btn4">Button</button>
  </div>

  <div id="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

However, I would also like not to use the green background in production. This means that `#navigation` should not have a background and only the buttons inside should be visible.

So my question is how do I hide the top-side overflow from `#card-wrapper` as soon as it reaches the hypothetical green background?

```css
#card-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #131418;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: inline-block
}

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: transparent
}

#main {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #c33764, #1d2671);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <div id="navigation"><button id="btn1">Button</button>
    <button id="btn2">Button</button>
    <button id="btn3">Button</button>
    <button id="btn4">Button</button>
  </div>

  <div id="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I am open to all solutions CSS/JS/jQuery as long as they do not involve hard-coded values

Comment: That's a smart workaround @VXp but won't work in this case because the background of the body element is not a solid color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it pure *CSS* while the `background` is set to `transparent`. A workaround would be to set it to the same `background` as of the `body` *element* and also set its `width` to `100%` to match the `width` of the `body` *element*:

```css
/* mandatory to match both backgrounds */
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}

#card-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #131418;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: inline-block
}

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 25px;
  /*border: 1px solid;*/
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #c33764, #1d2671); /* modified */
  width: 100%; /* added */
}

#main {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #c33764, #1d2671);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="navigation">
    <button id="btn1">Button</button>
    <button id="btn2">Button</button>
    <button id="btn3">Button</button>
    <button id="btn4">Button</button>
  </div>
  <div id="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks great, and answers the question as it is written, So, I will select it as the answer even though my problem still persists. The body element in my case has an SVG background and so I cannot just make that into the background for #navigation as well, it won't work. I added the gradient in my example to show that the background was not a solid color - for the sake of keeping the question simple. Thanks. I will keep trying other stuff.